# Unexpected key "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic6

I would like if someone can help me to solve this problem.

When I run the command ionic cap buils ios I get this error and when I open the project in xcode the info.plist file seems not to be visible.

```
`
[fatal] Error: Unexpected key "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" while parsing <dict/>.
[capacitor]     at invariant (/Users/ivanpala/Desktop/mascotas-anuncios-main/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:53:11)
[capacitor]     at parsePlistXML (/Users/ivanpala/Desktop/mascotas-anuncios-main/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:121:9)
[capacitor]     at parsePlistXML (/Users/ivanpala/Desktop/mascotas-anuncios-main/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:101:23)
[capacitor]     at Object.parse (/Users/ivanpala/Desktop/mascotas-anuncios-main/node_modules/plist/lib/parse.js:71:15)
[capacitor]     at logiOSPlist (/Users/ivanpala/Desktop/mascotas-anuncios-main/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/dist/cordova.js:273:43)`
```

I have tried to look for information in google and in different forums but I can't find a solution for this problem, if someone understands this error and can guide me I would appreciate it.

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>Mascota Anuncios</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Necesitamos acceder a la ubicacion para obtener una info precisa de su ubicacion actual</string>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It looks like you have an error in the structure of your info.plist file, but you haven't shown it so we can't help.  Probably a tag isn't closed.

Comment: hello thank you i am going to post the file see if you can help me

Comment: You have two `<key>`s in a row, which is invalid. It looks like the `<true/>` was originally after UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance but got separated.

Comment: </array>
 <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
  <true/>
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Necesitamos acceder a la ubicacion para obtener una info precisa de su ubicacion actual</string>

</dict>

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this solved the error, only now these warnings appear.

```
</array> <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key> <true/> <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> <string>Necesitamos acceder a la ubicación para obtener una información precisa de su ubicación actual</string> </dict>

[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
[capacitor]        <string>$PHOTO_LIBRARY_ADD_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
[capacitor]        <string>$PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION</string>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for ionic-plugin-deeplinks.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <string>$URL_SCHEME</string>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for cordova-plugin-googleplus.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <dict>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
[capacitor]        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
[capacitor]        <string>Editor</string>
[capacitor]        <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <string>$REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        </dict>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]        
[capacitor] [warn] Configuration required for onesignal-cordova-plugin.
[capacitor]        Add the following to Info.plist:
[capacitor]        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
[capacitor]        <array>
[capacitor]        <string>remote-notification</string>
[capacitor]        </array>
[capacitor]  

  I have to add those lines in info.plist as the message says, copy and paste I don't know much about this info.plist file between which labels I should put if they are to be copied.
```